# Docker container exits immediately despite Service Running

Tags: docker, ldap, docker-compose, dockerfile, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Similar questions seem to exist but none of them with clear answer (at least not to me). I've an LDAP Server inside a container which comes with `bin/start-ds` file. The problem is the container exits as soon as the shell script is finished. I'd understand the exit if script was simply printing a message, but in my case it starts a process. And since a process is running, i'd expect my container to run indefinitely as I started it in `detach` mode. But this is not the case and it exits immediately. Any pointers would be really appreciated. Below is my simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM unboundid-base:0.2
MAINTAINER helloworld

CMD ["/home/unboundid/UnboundID-DS/bin/start-ds"]
```

Comment: Can you please post your logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I guess, you use: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19623-01/820-6171/startds.html

So according to documentation add: --nodetach option

```
CMD ["/home/unboundid/UnboundID-DS/bin/start-ds", "--nodetach"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be two reason:

1. Add --nodetach

`CMD ["/home/unboundid/UnboundID-DS/bin/start-ds", "--nodetach"]`

2. Other reason why container exits immediately after you run it, is lack of resources. You might have enough resources, but there are multiple containers running at the same time which is consuming your resources. Or you are just running your container, but probably that container needs more resources to run and you are falling short of it.Allocate more resources, increase your ram and memory and trying running your container again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I run all of the UnboundID server products in docker containers for dev/test/troubleshooting.  My Dockerfile CMD line is:

```
CMD ${UBID_HOME}/bin/start-${UBID_PRODUCT};/bin/bash
```

As long as you leave a foreground process running the container will not exit and what better process to leave around than a shell to interact with the server.